# What is the purpose of these "stickers" in the F/A-18 Super Hornet fuselage?

Tags: fa-18, symbology

[image]

[image]

Photos source: screenshot from youtube video ->

I think they can be used as fuselage reference points in flight testing, but I'm not sure.

Are they part of NATO standard symbology?

Comment: These are definitely markers for some kind of tracking or video evaluation.

Comment: There's a big "STRIKE TEST" written on the sides of the fuselage, so I think your guess about reference points during flight testing is a likely situation.

Comment: That jet belongs to VX-23, which is a test and evaluation squadron from Pax River.

Answer (score 8):

It may or may not be being used in this application, but they are location markers, usually used in weapons separation tests to record the movement and behavior of stores in the airstream as they separate from the jet.  Camera pods, usually mounted on the wingtips or other optimal vantage points record the process for engineering purposes.